# How to use a GPIO pin after I put on a HAT?

Tags: gpio, hat

I got a Speaker pHAT for my Pi Zero. According to the [pinout](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/speaker_phat), it only uses 5 GPIO pins, so plenty of room to add something else.

The problem is, I'm not sure what's the best way to physically attach something after the hat is attached.

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Soldiering a wire directly to the pin on the other side of either the Pi or the hat. The downside here is that it would be permanent.
2. Wire wrapping around the male header between the Pi and the HAT. The [11mm header](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0174/1800/products/2x20_2_of_2_b5e0faab-d10d-4459-87de-89e54705b268_1024x1024.JPG) seems useful here as an extension of sorts, as it leaves plenty of room to wire wrap when attached:

[image: hat with 11mm header]

However, wire wrapping sounds flimsy at best.

Is there an elegant alternative to wire wrapping or perhaps some other means of attaching something to one of the unused pins when the HAT is on? Something like a ring tongue terminal that I could put on a single GPIO pin perhaps?

If not, what's the best way to go ahead with wire wrapping (i.e. any tips and tricks)?

Comment: They make boards that allow using multiple hats like this http://www.gearbest.com/arduino-scm-supplies/pp_311396.html?currency=USD&vip=760238&gclid=Cj0KEQjwrYbIBRCgnY-OluOk89EBEiQAZER58pBTx9NGS0lSQEyQPV-808DRXNfaPUozjWGcMfmTXvwaAs908P8HAQ

Comment: I know of these, but it seems like an overkill - I literally need a single pin to attach a sensor (and power, but I can draw this from a different source).

Comment: To do proper wire wrapping you need a tool and 30ga solid wire so it is not as simple as it sounds. Given that pressure is pounds divided by area, the the sharp corners have so little area the pressure is large enough to weld the wire to the pin.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a header that has extra long pins so that they stick as far past the speaker pHat as pins would normally stick?  I'm thinking something like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2223

Comment: That's the header I have - however, I already have the headers on both the Pi and the HAT soldiered, so I'm looking how I could actually use it?

Comment: what kind of header do you have on the pi?

Comment: and what kind of header is on the HAT?

Comment: The Pi has a male header, the HAT (on the photo) has a female one.

Comment: I'd remove the header on the HAT, and replace it with the extra long pin header you've got.  The pins will stick out the top side of the HAT and then you can use standard female jumper cables.  the female 40-pin on the bottom side of the hat can be plugged directly into the pi 40-pin male header

Comment: The stacking header is the way to go.  Anything else will likely not be all that reliable.  You might just need to remove the one that you have on there already and solder in a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could check on https://pinout.xyz/ which pins are actually needed by the HAT and use jumper wires to connect them, leaving the remaining ones accessible.