# Method for piling three peripherals on one pi

Tags: gpio, connectors

I'm working on my first pi project, which is intended to use the following three peripherals:

- GPS -- using UART ([pinout](https://github.com/FranzTscharf/Python-NEO-6M-GPS-Raspberry-Pi))
- eInk -- using SPI ([pinout](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/inky_phat#))
- battery power supply -- using I2C ([pintout](https://lifepo4wered.com/files/LiFePO4wered-Pi+-Product-Brief.pdf) on p. 15 of datasheet)

They're all using different buses/interfaces to talk to the pi, so it seems like this should work. I don't think powering them all should be a problem, since the eInk is an ultra-low-power device, and the battery is providing power rather than using it. Looking at the pinouts, the only pins that are used by more than one device seem to be various power and ground pins.

I've never done anything like this before, so I don't have any clear idea of how this works. What would be the most normal, straightforward way of putting all four boards (pi plus three peripherals) together mechanically and electrically? The eInk has its own 40-pin header, which is just intended to be connected to the pi's whole 40-pin header. The battery also seems to have a 40-pin connector, and is presumably designed to be sandwiched in between the pi board and other stuff; in the photo on p. 4 of the data sheet, it has some male prongs sticking up.

So do I need some additional piece of hardware that would go in this multilayered sandwich so that I can "break out" and make the four additional connections required by the GPS?

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66395/how-to-use-a-gpio-pin-after-i-put-on-a-hat

Comment: I later asked a modified and more fleshed-out version of this question on electronics.SE and got an answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445875/connectors-for-access-to-four-conductors-from-a-40-wire-ribbon-cable

Comment: I ended up doing this simply by soldering onto the bottom of the Pi.